# Tear (eye water) vs Tear (rip and rend)

Tags: word-usage, homophones

I'm working on a fiction story titled "The War of Tears". Now most people would read the last word, Tears, as the water that comes from ones eyes when emotional. However, I want it to be Tears, as in rips in spacetime (this is a particularly destructive war). Is there a way to specifically note that I am using the second definition of this word, while keeping the simple flow of the name?

Comment: Only publish your story as an audio book!

Comment: Definitely you can do it as an audio book.  A more interesting possibility to consider is to use a pun!

Comment: Replacing it with **The War of the Rifts** might work, though it'd entail major changes to the work itself.

Comment: You could explicitly add parenthetical *(rhymes with **airs**)* after the title. But that might not solve the problem for an audiobook (I'd naturally assume ***tares = weeds***, since it "sorta" makes sense to me, whereas ***tears = rents*** is just too weird in this exact context).

Comment: @VTH Something like that might work. I could go with a subtitle, The Rending, which would work for what they call the War 100 years later.

Comment: Odds are, this won't be an audiobook, and even if it is, the title is read as text by people deciding to listen, so the problem remains

Comment: I assume that the intended word will become obvious once somebody starts to read the book, reads the synopsis on the back jacket, or even looks at the cover art (depending on what it is). Even if the wrong assumption is made at first, it's still a catchy title that should "hook" people into looking at it more closely. (Trying to force comprehension is often a poor idea.)

Comment: How is that not more about style or personal choice, than English? Since you're here and you yourself said *The War of Tears* won't work, isn't it obvious that either something else is needed, or the author - ie, you - should present the story in a way that justifies such a title??

Comment: This is less English and more pictographs. If you want people to think tear it apart, the cover art of your book/title should be torn apart. Like a picture half way torn in two. Or the title torn in two. https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/two-halves-torn-paper-black-background-sheet-notebook-was-half-place-inscription-empty-182317181.jpg